# How to correct coordinate shifting in ax.annotate

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot-annotations

I tried to annotate a line plot with `ax.annotate` as follows.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_start = 0
x_end = 200
y_start = 20
y_end = 20

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5),dpi=600)
ax.plot(np.asarray([i for i in range(0,1000)]))
ax.annotate('', xy=(x_start, y_start), xytext=(x_end, y_end), xycoords='data', textcoords='data',
            arrowprops={'arrowstyle': '|-|'})
plt.show()
```

which gave a plot (zoomed in)

[image]

Although I have specified `x_start` to be `0` and `x_end` to be `200`, the actual start is greater than `0` and actual end is smaller than `200` on the x-axis.

How do I correctly line up this annotation with the set coordinates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the arrow is shrunk by 2 points on both ends (see the [doc](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html)). You can set `shrinkA` and `shrinkB` to 0 to align with your x-axis:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_start = 0
x_end = 200
y_start = 20
y_end = 20

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5),dpi=600)
ax.plot(np.asarray([i for i in range(0,1000)]))
ax.annotate('', xy=(x_start, y_start), xytext=(x_end, y_end), xycoords='data', textcoords='data',
            arrowprops={'arrowstyle': '|-|', 'shrinkA': 0, 'shrinkB': 0})
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]